# VSCode Color Picker not showing up on hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode [added a color picker](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_color-picker) a long time ago, but I'm not getting it to show up in my css files. For example:

```
.text {
    color: #000000;
}
```

When I hover over the hex code in a css file, nothing happens.

I have `Editor: Color Decorators` turned on, but that didn't work. How do I get it to show up?

About my VSCode:

```
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:37:28.172Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

Comment: Getting the exact same issue, starting today. Didn't have any issue with color picker not appearing until now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the PostCSS extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss